# How to create a SQLite database from 30 fasta files in R?

Tags: r, sqlite, fasta

I want to do an alignment of homologous regions of 30 multiple genomes with "DECIPHER" R package. I have the 30 sequences in fasta format, but package's function requires a sqlite database with the genomes.

I tried to use RSQLite's function  dbWriteTable, and the ones that appear in "sqldf" package, but they only seems to admit csv files.

Comment: According to the documentation of DECIPHER it is possible to use FASTA files. 
https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DECIPHER/inst/doc/ArtOfAlignmentInR.pdf , page 8 and following.

Comment: Directly it's possible to use FASTA files only for doing the alignment of a single gene. For full genomes is necessary to work with SQLite databases. In this vignette is not explained, but it someone has the same problem I found a function inside the package called Seqs2DB which, after creating an empty SQLite database, loads the fasta files into it.